# jquery search text of a label for existing occurrences

Tags: jquery

I'm adding tags to a label on click by doing the following in jQuery

```
$('.addTag').live('click', function () {

    $('.pendingTags').html($('.pendingTags').html() + $('.newTag').val() + ', ');

});
```

But what I need to do is see if the `$('.newTag').val()` already exists in the text/html of `.pendingTags`

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Add more details. What is the separator between the tags?

Comment: Sorry realised that wasn't in the code have updated the code with the separator which is a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.text()` method, rather than the `.html()` method. Also, you should add the comma before the new tag.

```
$('.addTag').live('click', function () {
    var currentTags = $('.pendingTags').text();  // Get current labels
    var newTag = $('.newTag').val();             // Get new label
    var listOfTags = currentTags.split(',');     // Create list of labels
    for(var i=0, l=listOfTags.length; i<l; i++) {// Loop through each
        if(listOfTags[i] == newTag) return;      // If the label exists, return
    }
    var sep = /^\s+$/.test(currentTags) ? "" : ","; // Create separator
    $('.pendingTags').text(currentTags + sep + newTag); //Not returned, add label
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.addTag').live('click', function () {

    if(!containsTag($('.pendingTags').html())
      $('.pendingTags').html($('.pendingTags').html() + $('.newTag').val() + ', ');
    else
      alert('you have it already');

});
function containsTag(val, tag)
{
   var tags = val.split(',')
   for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    {
        if($.trim(tags[$i]).toLowerCase() == tag.toLowerCase())
           return true;
    }
   return false;
}
```

I have created method which will check if tag exists in list of tags, case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.fn.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter down a jQuery object based on a callback:

```
$('.pendingTags')
//before adding the html, we filter the jquery set
.filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().split(', ').indexOf($('.newTag').val()) < 0;
})
//and only add the html to the new set
.html($('.pendingTags').html() + $('.newTag').val() + ', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/GXKFt/)):

```
$('.addTag').live('click', function () {
    var pending = $('.pendingTags').html();
    var newTag = $('.newTag').val();
    if((', ' + pending).indexOf(', ' + newTag + ', ') < 0) {
        $('.pendingTags').html(pending + newTag + ', ');
    }
});
```